Dynamic access to AzureDevOps YAML Pipeline Parameter
I have a template that gets an object parameter and a string parameter used to address a value in the object. Here I have different ways to print the values:
- name: valueName # the name of the attribute
  type: string

- name: secrets # array with secret info data (name, value)
  type: object
  default: []

jobs:
- ${{each secret in parameters.secrets}}:
    - job:
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "${{ secret['Development'] }}"
      - script: |
          echo "secret['${{ parameters.valueName}}']"
      - script: |
          echo "${{ secret['${{ parameters.valueName}}'] }}"

What I like to achieve is to access the value of the secret based on the value of the valueName parameter. So the object may look like this:
- name: secrets    
  type: object
  default: 
  - name: 'dbpassword'
    Development: 'demokey1'
    Staging: 'demokey2'
    Production: 'demokey3'

However, this is what the output of the 3 job steps is:
echo "demokey1"
echo "secret['Development']"
echo ""

Is there a way to resolve the parameter value by providing the nameas another parameter?

If I understood correctly you just need to get the right value for the environment (aka valueName) parameter?

In Azure Pipelines, it is not supported use a variable/parameter in the name of another variable/parameter.
For your case, you do like as below sample shows:
parameters:
- name: valueName
  type: string
  default: 'Development'

- name: secrets
  type: object
  default:
  - name: 'sec01'
    Development: 'dev01'
    Staging: 'stage01'
    Production: 'prod01'
  - name: 'sec02'
    Development: 'dev02'
    Staging: 'stage02'
    Production: 'prod02'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - ${{ each secret in parameters.secrets }}:
    - job: A_${{ secret.name }}
      steps:
      . . .

      - ${{ each item in secret }}:
        - ${{ if eq(item.Key, parameters.valueName) }}:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'Show Infor'
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                echo "item.Key = ${{ item.Key }}"
                echo "item.Value = ${{ item.Value }}"
                echo "parameters.valueName = ${{ parameters.valueName }}"



I implemented it within 5 minutes and it works like a charm. Thx!

If I understood correctly you're trying to get the secret for the environment you pass as the valueName parameter:

Production
Staging
Development

You can simplify the design of your pipeline using regular variables, as opposed to complex parameters.
First step would be to create a variables template:
# /pipelines/variables/secret-variables.yaml

parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: 'Environment name (e.g. Production, Staging, Development)'
    type: string

variables:
  # Note: for sensitive data, it is recommended to use variables groups!!!

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Development') }}:
    - name: secret
      value: demokey1
  
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Staging') }}:
    - name: secret
      value: demokey2
  
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'Production') }}:
    - name: secret
      value: demokey3

And then you just need to reference the variables template setting the environment parameter - example pipeline:
name: test-pipeline-4

parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: 'Environment name'
    type: string
    default: Development
    values:
      - Development
      - Staging
      - Production

trigger: none

pool: 
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - job: test
    variables:
      - template: /pipelines/variables/secret-variables.yaml
        parameters:
          environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Secret: $(secret)"
        displayName: 'Print secret'

